# Overwriting component inside module without modifying module

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular, is it possible to extend a component that exists inside of an external module and then use that new component as a part of the module without modifying the module itself?

I'm able to extend the component and add additional functionality to it, but i'm unsure of how to connect this new component to the module. I want to keep the module untouched so that it can be updated without having to worry about modifying the new files each time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can extend components. Just add it normally to the module. Check this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2) to learn more.

> Component inheritance DO NOT cover templates and styles. Any shared
>   DOM or behaviours must be handled separately.